# Update Realm database

Tags: objective-c, realm

I'm trying to update the Realm database, but can't figure it out.

I was using `[realm addObject:info];`, but that would just add the same objects to the Realm database that already existed.

So then I replaced that with `[People createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:info];` but that only added the last item in my array of People information (there are six People, but the Realm database would only show the sixth person information).

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

**People.h:**

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *fname;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *lname;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *flName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *phone;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *video;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *pdf;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *pKey;

+ (NSString *)primaryKey;
```

**People.m:**

```
+ (NSString *)primaryKey
{
    return @"pKey";
}
```

**TableViewController.m:**

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
for (id item in responseArray) {
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];

    People *info = [[People alloc] init];
    info.fname = item[@"fname"];
    info.lname = item[@"lname"];
    info.flName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", item[@"fname"], item[@"lname"]];
    info.phone = item[@"phone"];
    info.video = item[@"video"];
    info.pdf = item[@"pdf"];

    [People createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:info];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

The `responseArray` comes from data from an API.

Comment: you placed RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm]; in loop, so it will get over written everytime. PLace it outside the loop

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I will update my code.  I'm still getting the same issue though for some reason?

Comment: The placement of the call to ` [RLMRealm defaultRealm]` is not relevant to whatever problem you're seeing.

Comment: [realm addObject:info]; shud work. Try placing it in a block. [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
  [realm addObject:info];
}];

Comment: @bdash good to know.  I feel like there's something missing between how I'm understanding using the subclass and primary key, or something.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I tried `[realm addObject:info];` before and it didn't work, but it wasn't in a block.  So I'll try putting it in a block, does all the other code go inside of that block too, or is it just `[realm addObject:info];`?

Comment: It's jsut that one line goes into the block.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri got it.  If I do that I get a crash due to "The Realm is already in a write transaction"

Comment: see this documentation about adding to realm. https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/ . If you are doing it from another class, try doing it as suggested in the documentaiton.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yeah I looked thru that and couldn't find the missing piece of what I was doing wrong, so I figured I'd ask on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide the definition of the `+primaryKey` method, but my suspicion is that your `pKey` property is your primary key. You're not setting the `pKey` property on the `info` object you create, which results in it being left at its default value of `nil`. This means `+createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:` sees you asking to update the same object each time through the loop: the object with a primary key of `nil`.

Setting the `pKey` property on `info` before calling `+createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:` should result in all of the objects being saved as you expect.

Note also that it's preferable to minimize the number of write transactions, as each write transaction has a certain amount of overhead. In this case you can easily move the write transaction outside of the loop.

Comment: This sounds pretty much like what I thought it might be, but I'm still a bit hazy on how to implement the correct understanding.  I added my `People.m` file in my question so you could see it.  So should I keep setting the `pKey` in `People`.h/.m, and should I do it how I'm doing it right now?  And then would my `TableViewController.m` stay the same, or should I be doing something different there? I'm sorry to have you help me suss this out a bit further, but it makes sense enough for me to have a hazy idea of what's wrong, but not enough to unlock how to fully implement correct.

Comment: I think the only change you need to make is for the code in your loop within `TableViewController.m` to give the `pKey` property a value. Presumably the `item` dictionary provides a unique identifier that allows you to identify each `People` instance, so that an existing object with that identifier can be updated rather than duplicated.

Comment: Sadly the `item` dictionary does not provide a unique identifier to identify each `People` instance.  I'm assuming other people have also had that problem too, so I'm still searching around for a solution to that because there has to be one on that

Comment: I tried adding `info.pKey = @"pKey";` into the loop code, but I just get zero results when I do that

Comment: The primary key functions as a unique identifier for a given object. Giving every object the same value defeats the purpose of using a primary key. Are you sure you need a primary key at all? Are you expecting the code you shared from `TableViewController.m` to ever update existing objects? If so, how do you want to determine which existing object to update?

Comment: Right, yeah the unique identifier should be different but it's not super clear how Realm wants me to handle that, so I'm with you there.  I'm not sure that I need a primary key at all either, but when I use `[People createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:info];` I only get one person saved instead of all six (and the one person that gets saved is the last, so I'm guessing its writing over each person as it runs thru the loop).  So then I wasn't sure if that's what I needed the primary key for or not? Because I'm assuming the `TVC.m` to update/add objects from the API it is pulling from.

Comment: I assumed it was easy to do in Realm and thats why people would use Realm, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here

Comment: Same thing happens when I use `[realm addOrUpdateObject:info];` too instead of `[People createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:info];`

Comment: Let's take a step back: Should `TableViewController.m` ever update existing objects, or are you only wanting to add new objects? If you want it to update existing objects, how should it determine which object to update given the information available to it in the `item` dictionary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118259/discussion-between-bdash-and-srmr).